# How can I use wget to create a list of URLs from an index.html?

Tags: wget, recursive

So `wget` has an ability to recursively download files, however it does it one file at a time.

I would like to pass in a directory URL, and for each URL it encounters in the recursion for it to spawn off a downloading process.

One way I was thinking to do this is to somehow use `wget` to print out the URLs it encounters, and then feeding those URLs into separate instances of `wget` (via `wget URL_1 &`, `wget URL_2 &` etc).

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if `wget` is the right tool for the job here. Are you totally dead-set on using wget? In the year 2022, there are probably better tools for getting a list of links from an arbitrary URL, _e.g._, [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/), [xidel](https://www.videlibri.de/xidel.html), or [pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been ruminating on this, and I'm not convinced wget is the best tool for the job here.

Here is how I would do this in the year 2022, using a tool like [pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup) that is specifically designed to parse HTML (in pup's case, with [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference#selectors)):

```bash
wget -q -O- https://ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads \
  | pup 'a[href$=".torrent"] attr{href}' \
  | aria2c -d ~/Downloads -i -
```

#### See also

- [xidel](https://www.videlibri.de/xidel.html)

  - the `-e` / `--extract` option uses [XPath selectors](https://devhints.io/xpath) by default; supports CSS selectors with `--css '<selector>'` or `--extract 'css("<selector>")'`
  - can fetch internet resources directly—a bit slower than `curl` on my machine, though
  - very tolerant parser; almost never seen it complain, even for malformed HTML
  - examples:

    ```bash
    xidel https://www.videlibri.de/xidel.html \
          -e '//a[ends-with(@href,"/download")]/@href'

    # faster, for some reason; don't forget the '-' (read from stdin)!
    curl -q https://www.videlibri.de/xidel.html \
      | xidel -e '//a[ends-with(@href,"/download")]/@href' -

    # same as above, using CSS selectors + XPath for the attribute
    curl -q https://www.videlibri.de/xidel.html \
      | xidel -e 'css("a[href$=/download]")/@href' -
    ```
- [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)

  - uses XPath selectors
  - *must* have well-formed XML/XHTML as input

    - piping through `xmlstarlet fo -H -R` (re**fo**rmat, expect input as **H**TML, try to **R**ecover after errors) should fix for most web sites
  - example:

    ```bash
    # NB: my version of xmlstarlet doesn't support XPath 'ends-with'
    curl -s https://ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads \
      | xmlstarlet fo -H -R 2>/dev/null \
      | xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//a[contains(@href, ".torrent")]/@href' -n
    ```
- [aria2](https://github.com/aria2/aria2)

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep` with it:

```
wget url -rqO - | grep -oE '[a-z]+://[^[:space:]"]+'
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem is to collect all the links in a plain text file and do the following:-

```
while read line; do
    echo "Downloading ${line}"
    wget $line &        
done < $1
```

Save this file as **script.sh** and make it executable and run it as

```
$ ./script.sh
```

*A better way to permanently solve this problem would be to rewrite wget to be inherently parallel.*

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it worked by *chaining* two `wget`s:

```
$ wget -O - -o /dev/null http://site.to.get.urls.from | grep -o 'some_regex' | wget -i -
```

The first `wget` will produce a list of URLs with files, which is used as input "file" for the second `wget`.

Note that this is a *simplified* version to show you the technique behind it. The pipe between the `grep` and the second `wget` command might in fact be combined with way more piped commands like `sed`, `awk` or `cut` (especially if the HTML source code is a little more complex than usual and hence parsing it is more difficult).

**This reads**: Always make sure you call the inner `wget` standalone first to verify on `stdout` that your regular expression(s) is (are) working correctly.